# How can I shift ymin to zero when values are near to zero?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I shift `ymin` to zero when values are near to zero? I also try `ymin=0` command but it does not work.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar, ymax=4,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Surface Roughness (nm)},
xlabel={Substrate},
symbolic x coords={Glass,Silicon,PEN},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot [fill= white] coordinates {(Glass,2.4) (Silicon,1.1) (PEN,1.8)};
\addplot [fill = black] coordinates  {(Glass,1.1) (Silicon,0.2) (PEN,1.0)};

\legend{Profilometer,AFM}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Substrate Vs IBD Surface Roughness(Avg)}
\label{Subvibd}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a few more lines to make your code a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem such that people can directly copy/paste and work on the problem.

Comment: I want that my ybars starts from exactly zero. I don't want any empty space between starting the ybar and x-axis. Thanks

Comment: Remove `enlargelimits=0.15` and put `ymin=0`. But I was mentioning about making your code copy/paste compilable.

Comment: Glad that you have solved your problem but I feel that I can't make my point clear.

Comment: Actually the problem was that, I want the ybars should start from zero of x-axis but they were starting with some space because the zero value of y-axis was shifted upwards. But now its ok after removing the enlarglimit. :)

Answer (score 5):

Removing `enlargelimits=0.15` and introducing `ymin=0` again, would make the y-axis start from `0`.